# Remove a child when clicking on a button

Tags: actionscript-3

I’ve got a little problem. I’ve created a menu before the game start, with a “start”, “load” and “quit” button. It’s in a new class named IntroScreen.as.

So, the engine class (Engine.as) calls  the Introscreen just after the cinematic :

```
private function ouvertureMenu(e:MouseEvent):void{
removeChild(opening);
introScreen.visible = true;
options.changeMusic(“”);
```

Perfect from here.

When I click on the “load” button, it calls an other class named SaveRestore.as where there are all the functions for the saves and restore. 
So, the window Save/Restore open.

BUT when I restore a game, the saverestore window closes but not the Introscreen ! (I heard (music background) that my game is loaded in background).

So I want to make my IntroScreen not visible when I click on “restore”.

I don’t understand why it’s not working. I’ve put a “removeChild(introScreen) in the SaveRestore.as like that :

```
…
// Restore game data
if(allSaveData){
puzzle.restorePuzzles(allSaveData.puzzleStatus);
inv.restoreInv(allSaveData.currentInv, allSaveData.allInv);
options.restoreOptions(allSaveData.optset);

Engine.newBack = allSaveData.playerLoc.room;
addEventListener(“repose”, reposePlayer);
stageRef.dispatchEvent(new Event(“changeBackground”));
showConfirm(“restored”, slotNum);
removeChild(introScreen);
dispatchEvent(new Event(“closeThis”));
} else {
trace (“No save data found”);
Engine.restoring = false;
}
```

Do you know what could be the problem ? Why the introscreen is still visible (the removeChild isn’t working)
(I'm using the [ALPACA open source code](http://www.alpacaengine.com/docs))

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the owner of introScreen is Engine, and that is where you would need to be calling removeChild from. Maybe work around it like this?

```
  //in Engine.as:
  public function removeIntro():void
  { //logic here, including removeChild(...)
  }

  //in SaveRestore.as
  engineRef.removeIntro();
```

Comment: and Engine.removeIntro();  is making the error 1061..(static Class)

Comment: My solution assumes some sort of encapsulation was enforced in the app. This may not apply.